# No such module 'FIRStorageMetadata'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods

When trying to import the FIRStorageMetadata it's giving error:

```
No such module 'FIRStorageMetadata'
```

In my pod file, I have these pods for Firebase:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FIRStorageMetadata` should be in `Storage`:

```
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
```